# gF with given word as delimiter between filename and line number

Tags: filenames

I know Vim's gF can work on this pattern:

```
swank.lisp:1694
```

However, how can I tune `gF` to work with the slimv's cross-reference giving pattern:

```
swank.lisp line 1694
```

Thanks！

Comment: According to `:help gF` this should actually work: *"" line " is also recognized, like it is used in the output of :verbose command UserCmd"*, and if I try it then it seems to work for me. What happens when you enter `gF`? Do you get an error? Also, what Vim version are you using?

Comment: Thanks Martin. With the " line ", gF just opens the file without moving to the specific line. My Vim's version is VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)
Included patches: 1-1453
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.

Comment: It looks like this feature was added in [Vim 8.2.0030](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/64e74c9cc) from Dec 2019; one way to make it work is updating your Vim to a more recent version. Otherwise the only option is override `gF` with some custom VimScript which implements this.

Comment: Thanks very much, Martin. I update my Vim to the latest version and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin notes in the comments, support for this was added in [8.2.0030](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/64e74c9cc) in December of 2019. An upgrade solves it.

Otherwise, you'll need to override `gF` with some vimscript.